# Replace text with HTML element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, replace

How can I replace a specific text with HTML objects?

example:

```
var text = "some text to replace here.... text text text";

var element = $('<img src="image">').event().something...

function ReplaceWithObject(textSource, textToReplace, objectToReplace);
```

So I want to get this:

```
 "some text to replace < img src...etc >.... text text text"
```

And I would like manipulate the object element without call again `$()` method.

**UPDATE:**
I solved.

thanx @kasdega, i made a new script based in your script, because in your script i can't modify the "element" after replace.
This is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var text = "some text to replace here.... text text text";
    var element = $('<img />');

    text = text.split('here');
    $('.result').append(text[0],element,text[1]);
$(element).attr('src','http://bit.ly/mtUXZZ');
    $(element).width(100);
});
```

I didnt know that append method accept multiples elements.
That is the idea, only need to automate for multiple replacements

thanx to all, and here the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MxRma/21/)

Answer (score 4):

do a split on the text you want to replace then use the array indexes 0 and 1...something like:

```
function ReplaceWithObject(textSource, textToReplace, objectToReplace) {
    var strings = textSource.split(textToReplace);
    if(strings.length >= 2) {
        return strings[0] + objectToReplace.outerHTML() + strings[1];
    }
    return "";
}
```

UPDATE: I found another SO post [Get selected element's outer HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html) that pointed me to a tiny jquery plugin that helps here.

I believe this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/MxRma/) has what you want.  outerHTML is the tiny jquery plugin I included in the JSFiddle.

You can also use replace which will reduce some code: http://jsfiddle.net/kasdega/MxRma/1/

```
function ReplaceWithObject(textSource, textToReplace, objectToReplace) {
    return textSource.replace(textToReplace, objectToReplace.outerHTML());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function textToObj (text,obj,$src){
    var className = "placeholder-"+text;
    $src.html($src.html().replace(text,"<div class='"+className+"'></div>"));
    $("."+className).replace(obj);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use $(selector).outerHtml to get the html string of an element

Comment: ok. i do this: var obj = $('<element>'); 'some string 2 replace'.replace('string',$(obj).outerHTML); but when i try do this $(obj).click(function(){console.log('works!');}); dont work.

Answer (score -2):

You can replace the html directly: http://jsfiddle.net/rkw79/qNFKF/

$(selector).html(function(i,o) {
    return o.replace('old_html','new_html');
})

Comment: This does not answer the question: "Replace **text** with **HTML** element.